# Вывести из массива нужную строку

Tags: php

Господа, есть вот такой код для вывода массива:

```
<?      
$db =&JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "SELECT field_id,item_id,value FROM a68y5_fields_values WHERE field_id='27'";
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadObjectList();
print_r($result);
?>
```

Получаем такой вывод:

```
Array([0] =&gt; stdClass Object([field_id] =&gt; 27[item_id] =&gt; 57[value] =&gt; {"items":[{"caption":"","thumbnail":"media\/acfgallery\/content\/57\/27\/turkue-2_thumb.jpg","image":"media\/acfgallery\/content\/57\/27\/turkue-2.jpg"},{"caption":"","thumbnail":"media\/acfgallery\/content\/57\/27\/cei-tr-17-20_thumb.jpg","image":"media\/acfgallery\/content\/57\/27\/cei-tr-17-20.jpg"},{"caption":"","thumbnail":"media\/acfgallery\/content\/57\/27\/376e2e826ef05422273ec4ce4aeea6a7_thumb.jpg","image":"media\/acfgallery\/content\/57\/27\/376e2e826ef05422273ec4ce4aeea6a7.jpg"},{"caption":"","thumbnail":"media\/acfgallery\/content\/57\/27\/20210408193043834296329o_thumb.jpg","image":"media\/acfgallery\/content\/57\/27\/20210408193043834296329o.jpg"},{"caption":"","thumbnail":"media\/acfgallery\/content\/57\/27\/azura_park_room_1_thumb.jpg","image":"media\/acfgallery\/content\/57\/27\/azura_park_room_1.jpg"}]})[1] =&gt; stdClass Object([field_id] =&gt; 27[item_id] =&gt; 56[value] =&gt; {"items":{"0":{"caption":"","thumbnail":"media\/acfgallery\/content\/56\/27\/cei-tr-17-20_thumb.jpg","image":"media\/acfgallery\/content\/56\/27\/cei-tr-17-20.jpg"},"1":{"caption":"","thumbnail":"media\/acfgallery\/content\/56\/27\/turkue-2_thumb.jpg","image":"media\/acfgallery\/content\/56\/27\/turkue-2.jpg"},"2":{"caption":"","thumbnail":"media\/acfgallery\/content\/56\/27\/376e2e826ef05422273ec4ce4aeea6a7_thumb.jpg","image":"media\/acfgallery\/content\/56\/27\/376e2e826ef05422273ec4ce4aeea6a7.jpg"},"3":{"caption":"","thumbnail":"media\/acfgallery\/content\/56\/27\/20210408193043834296329o_thumb.jpg","image":"media\/acfgallery\/content\/56\/27\/20210408193043834296329o.jpg"},"5":{"caption":"","thumbnail":"media\/acfgallery\/content\/56\/27\/azura_park_room_1_thumb.jpg","image":"media\/acfgallery\/content\/56\/27\/azura_park_room_1.jpg"},"6":{"caption":"","thumbnail":"media\/acfgallery\/content\/56\/27\/27173286512962220648konak-city-towers-in-alanya_13_thumb.jpg","image":"media\/acfgallery\/content\/56\/27\/27173286512962220648konak-city-towers-in-alanya_13.jpg"}}}))
```

Как я могу вывести только то что содержится в 56[value] => Т.е. нужен вот этот код:

```
{"items":{"0":{"caption":"","thumbnail":"media\/acfgallery\/content\/56\/27\/cei-tr-17-20_thumb.jpg","image":"media\/acfgallery\/content\/56\/27\/cei-tr-17-20.jpg"},"1":{"caption":"","thumbnail":"media\/acfgallery\/content\/56\/27\/turkue-2_thumb.jpg","image":"media\/acfgallery\/content\/56\/27\/turkue-2.jpg"},"2":{"caption":"","thumbnail":"media\/acfgallery\/content\/56\/27\/376e2e826ef05422273ec4ce4aeea6a7_thumb.jpg","image":"media\/acfgallery\/content\/56\/27\/376e2e826ef05422273ec4ce4aeea6a7.jpg"},"3":{"caption":"","thumbnail":"media\/acfgallery\/content\/56\/27\/20210408193043834296329o_thumb.jpg","image":"media\/acfgallery\/content\/56\/27\/20210408193043834296329o.jpg"},"5":{"caption":"","thumbnail":"media\/acfgallery\/content\/56\/27\/azura_park_room_1_thumb.jpg","image":"media\/acfgallery\/content\/56\/27\/azura_park_room_1.jpg"},"6":{"caption":"","thumbnail":"media\/acfgallery\/content\/56\/27\/27173286512962220648konak-city-towers-in-alanya_13_thumb.jpg","image":"media\/acfgallery\/content\/56\/27\/27173286512962220648konak-city-towers-in-alanya_13.jpg"}}}
```

Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = array_column($result, 'value', 'item_id');
//print_r($data[56]);
$value = json_decode($value[56]);
foreach ($values->items as $item){
     print_r([$item->caption, $item->thumbnail]);
}
```